# How do I add a simple test iAd to a new view-based application?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, iad

I have searched youtube and google and tried to figure out how to simply put a test iAd in an app. I added the iAd framework, imported it, and added code under the view did load method to try to make an iAd. I have tried different tutorials and followed instructions with still no success. Is there an expert who knows how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app